# How to gray out unused C++ variables in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, c++, visual-studio-code, unused-variables, unused-functions

VSCode grays out unused variables/imports in JS and TS files.

I use VSCode for writing C++ code also and I have the C/C++ extension installed too.
I want VSCode to also **gray out unused C++ variables** in my code and maybe also show a warning (if possible), which isn't the case at present in VSCode.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this in VSCode?

Comment: that is controlled by the semantic highlighting of the language server, create an issue at the cpp extension

Comment: Okay got it, Thank you! I will do that.